# Textarea Store and Show Linebreaks

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have an Angular 2 App and I use a textarea:

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="value"></textarea>
```

The value gets sent via a REST Api to the server. However already in the application when I want to show:

```
{{value}}
```

It won't show line breaks. How can I accomplish this? It should show the line breaks and ensure that these are also saved in the model.

Comment: `<pre>{{value}}</pre>`

Comment: But <pre> limits me in case of styling

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a HTML question. Play on the `white-space` property (`pre` tags have it by default) :

```js
const tags = [...document.querySelectorAll('#pre, #formatted, #unformatted')];
tags.forEach(tag => tag.innerHTML = "Content\nWith a line break & return");
```

```css
#formatted {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<p>in a pre tag : </p>
<pre id="pre"></pre>

<p>in a formatted tag : </p>
<div id="formatted"></div>

<p>in a unformatted tag : </p>
<div id="unformatted"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea  style="white-space: pre;" [(ngModel)]="value"></textarea>
```

your value might be like this:

```
value = "1234\n5678"
```

"\n" as linebreaks